# How do I get rid of this line below list item when using padding?

Tags: html, css, padding

I am having a problem where when I add padding to the list item "About Us" where it adds a line of background color down when I add padding to the list item. It is hard to explain but if you copy and paste the code into an html document and open it in a browser it will make much more sense. I am too new to these forums for it to let me post an image.

I apologize, but I am just getting into coding and so am struggling a little bit.

Thanks!

```
<!--Begin HTML-->
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
    <img src="Bend-oregon-dentist.jpg">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About Us
        <ul>
                <li>Our Services</li>
                <li>Our Office</li>
            </ul>
       </li>
   </ul>            
    </header>

</body>
</html>
<!--End HTML-->

/*BEGIN CSS*/
body {
margin: 0;
}
header  {
background: rgba(8,118,71,1.00);
    height: 175px;
}
#nav {

     list-style: none;
     text-align: center;
     padding-bottom: 0px;
     margin-bottom: 0px;

}
#nav li {
     margin-left: 10px;
     display: inline;
     color: white;
     font-family: verdana;
     background: rgba(3, 78, 3, 0.96);
     padding: 2px;
     border-top-left-radius: 15px;
     border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}
#nav ul{
    list-style: none;
}
#nav ul li  {
    display: none;
}
#nav li:hover ul    {
    height: 20px;
}
#nav li:hover ul li {
    margin-left: 899px;
display: block;
background: rgba(174,175,185,0.9);
    width: 79px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    text-align: left;
    color: black;
    font-size: 12px;
}
  /*END CSS*/
```

Comment: cssdeck here: http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/z2cfzlc1

Comment: not sure where you got that code from but you should google tutorials for css dropdown menus.

Comment: It's important to recognise the differernce between `padding` and `margin`. Padding add space inside and elements border, hence the additional background color. Margin adds space outside the elements border.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Your menu needs many chages.  see [**this updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/ew7ek/1/)

```
#nav {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
#nav li {
    margin-left: 10px;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    font-family: verdana;
    background: rgba(3, 78, 3, 0.96);
    padding: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}
#nav ul {
    list-style: none;
}
#nav li {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}
#nav li > ul {
    position:absolute;
    top: 38px;
    left: -50px;
    width:200px;
    display: none;
}
#nav li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    color: black;
    font-size: 12px;
    height:auto;
}
```